# changing the dtype of numpy array affects the data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

While I'm playing around with numpy,

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
x
```

it returns `array([[0, 1, 2],[3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8]])`

but once I change the datatype by

```
x.dtype=np.int8
x
```

now x becomes `array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0],[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0],[6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0]], dtype=int8)`, and `x.shape` returns `(3, 24)`.

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know why that is happening, but you probably want `x.astype(np.int8)`

Answer (score 6):

When you change the `dtype` the way you do it, you do not change the data, but the interpretation of it. That means that for each int64 (your standard int type) you get 8 int8 values. And with the LSB order of bytes in memory, the lowest 8 bits (i.e., the lowest byte) are first, giving you your number (as long as it is smaller than 256) followed by 7 zeros.

What you probably want to do, is to convert the data, and generate a new memory layout, generating a new array from the old one, this can be done e.g. by:

```
x=np.array(x, dtype=np.int8)
```

or simpler:

```
x.astype(np.int8)
```

Comment: So `dtype` can be changed directly like `shape`.  But I never seen it done before; I'm not sure it's even sanctioned in the docs.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, you probably don't want to do it, as the result is not likely to be very portable. It has to do with the underlying representation in c. Thus, depending on architecture, it may be LSB or MSB, and, at least in theory dependent on the element size and padding of the underlying c array.

Answer (score 0):

[dtype.gist link](https://gist.github.com/deepclearning/1df359bff3dbe6134ea46fc08102d3bb)

I have played your code and observed that when you change the data-type of numpy array then according dtype that the array elements are in now and what were earlier affect the number of elements right now in the array. Let discuss more
In my case earlier dtype of numpy array was int32 and I changed it into

```
dtype = np.int8
```

so 32 / 8 = 4, each elements are now appended by 3 addition zero, and I think in your case earlier numpy array dtype was

```
dtype = np.int64
```

that why each elements is appended by 7 zeros.

so now element of array is 8 bit but in memory it was allocated 32 bit(in my case) and 64 bit in your case. That's why rest memory is allocated now zero.

One more thing, Now if you change the x[0,0] to such value, 8 bit can't hold it will show something else than your value. So this is all about the memory allocation.

I hope this will help you